# Factory pattern return generic types in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, factory-pattern

```
public interface IRequestProcessor<out T>
{    
   T Translate(string caseId);
}

public class xyzReqProcessor : IRequestProcessor<xyzType>
{
  public xyzType Process(string xyzMsg)
  {
     return new xyz();
  }
}
public class VHDReqProcessor : IRequestProcessor<VHDType>
{
  public VHDType Process(string xyzMsg)
  {
     return new VHD();
  }
}
```

till here it looks good.
now i want to initialize the class with factory but it's not able to return IRequestProcessor type of object.

```
public static IRequestProcessor Get(FormType translatorType)
{

  IRequestProcessor retValue = null;
  switch (translatorType)
  {
    case EFormType.VHD:
      retValue = new VHDProcessor();
      break;
    case EFormType.XYZ: 
      retValue = new XYZProcessor();
      break;
  }
  if (retValue == null)
    throw new Exception("No Request processor found");

  return retValue;

}
```

at the time of calling Factory.Get(FormType translatorType) method I dont want to specify any fixed object type like below

> Factory.Get< XYZType>(FormType translatorType)

Comment: Well you could declare that it returns `IRequestProcessor<object>`. But the caller would have to cast the result of calling `Translate` (or `Process`; the question is inconsistent.)

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile-time, you cannot use strong typing.

Comment: @JonSkeet :  no, if i wanted to use Object then i could have simple used it without generics.

Comment: Well how do you expect to get a *compile-time safe* value back from a value that's only known at *execution* time? If I call `FormType type = GetFormTypeFromSomewhere(); var processor = Factory.Get(type);` what would you want the *compile-time* type of `processor` to be?

Comment: @JonSkeet: IRequestProcessor type of object.

Comment: But there is no IRequestProcessor type shown in the post... and the only common base type between types in the post is ‘object’

Comment: You can achieve something close to that with the following condition: 1) have base class of the processor 2) create IRequestProcessor and IRequestProcessor<T> : IRequestProcessor and then within implementation route these methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this solution fits into your overall design but with this trick you can achieve what you have asked for. The point is to have two interfaces, one generic and one not where the not generic interface route calls to generic one. See bellow:

```
public abstract class BaseType
{
    public abstract void Execute();
}

public class VhdType : BaseType
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vhd");
    }
}

public class XyzType : BaseType
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Xyz");
    }
}

public interface IRequestProcessor
{
    BaseType Process();
}

public interface IRequestProcessor<T> : IRequestProcessor where T : BaseType, new()
{
    T Process<TInput>() where TInput : T;
}

public class VhdRequestProcessor : IRequestProcessor<VhdType>
{
    public BaseType Process()
    {
        return Process<VhdType>();
    }

    public VhdType Process<TInput>() where TInput : VhdType
    {
        return new VhdType();
    }
}

public class XyzRequestProcessor : IRequestProcessor<XyzType>
{
    public BaseType Process()
    {
        return Process<XyzType>();
    }

    public XyzType Process<TInput>() where TInput : XyzType
    {
        return new XyzType();
    }
}

public class RequestFactory
{
    public IRequestProcessor GetRequest(string requestType)
    {
        switch (requestType)
        {
            case "vhd": return new VhdRequestProcessor();
            case "xyz": return new XyzRequestProcessor();
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid request");
    }            
}
```

Usage example:

```
IRequestProcessor req = new RequestFactory().GetRequest("xyz");
BaseType r = req.Process();
r.Execute();
```